# How can I add an icon to a boomark in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome

I've got a nice little Read it Later bookmarklet, but without a favicon it looks like this:

[image]

It doesn't appear to come with a Favicon, but I'd really like it to have the Read It Later icon so I could remove the label. Is there any way to do this? All I can do with it in Bookmark Manager is edit the label/link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here is a tutorial](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/3032/google_chrome_how_to_change_icons_on_the_bookmarks_bar/) that makes the way to do this, for this you have to download the [SQLite Database Driver](http://sourceforge.net/project/showfiles.php?group_id=87946).
Also take a look on this [Chrome Addon](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/laggbmpbikikiablknnppgglelkncemk).